# Close database connection in connection pool

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, tomcat7, connection-pooling

I am using JDBC connection pool to make connection with mysql server.

Below is my code snippet

```
  try {
       InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
        Context context = (Context) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env"); 
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) context.lookup("connpool");
        Connection conn =  ds.getConnection();
        //some query is executed 
    }
    catch(SQLException ex)
   {   } 
   finally {  conn.close(); }
```

*My Doubt:*

My doubt here is even I am making connection close(conn.close()), in MySQL
**show processlist** command it showing connection.

If I send more requests to servlet the connections count in show processlist is also increasing,

When this connection will be closed.

Why I am afraid means it it reached max connections count it will show error.

My Connection pool configuration is:

```
          <Resource name="connpool" auth="Container" 
             type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
             maxActive="1" maxIdle="0"
             maxWait="-1"
             username="xxxxx" 
             password="xxxxx"
             driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
             url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/govsocial"/>
```

Comment: Check the configuration of your datasource. Probably it's opening a new connection until it reaches the max of allowed connections, then it will start reusing them.

Comment: The connection pool may not actually close the _physical_ database connection when you issue `conn.close`, but rather just free it up for use by another `getConnection`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I have set maxActive="1" maxIdle="0" maxWait="-1"

Comment: Can you post your full configuration for the connection pool?  What library are you using?

Comment: @JohnR I have added the resource configuration in the post.

Answer (score 0):

From [tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html), there are initial values that are not set consistently with what you are setting in the resource config.

- `minIdle` (default is 10)
- `initialSize` (default is 10)

If you have a [look at the code for `init()` method](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/7.0.59/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/ConnectionPool.java#ConnectionPool), with the above defaults and your configuration with

- `maxActive = "1"`
- `maxIdle = "0"`

You will end up with:

- `maxActive = "1"`
- `maxIdle = "1"`
- `minIdle = "1"`
- `initialSize = "1"`

This is a pool of 1 connection, and the purpose of the pool is to keep some (depending on config) connections open for incoming requests. Calling `close()` will only pass the connection from the *busy* queue to the *idle* one.

If you really want **no pool** at all, you should try setting explicitly:

- `maxActive = "1"`
- `maxIdle = "0"`
- `minIdle = "0"`
- `initialSize = "0"`

Note that `maxWait = -1` means a new connection will wait until a connection is available - without timeout.